# .htaccess rewrite to subdir can't find its subdirs

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I'm about to lose my mind over a .htaccess issue, which i'm apparently not able to solve.

what i'm trying to accomplish is:

```
rewrite: example.com -> www.example.com -> /subdir/
```

What i've got so far is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /subdir/$1 [L]
```

**This works, but then the server can't find the subdirs in the subdir, like the (/subdir/)css dir.**

hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the last line should be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]
```

Also if you ommit the L in [R=301,L], it should be a little bit faster (at last in theory).

Comment: Well, I cant explain the "moved permanently" page, but I am happy for you that it works

Comment: Hi Jannis, sorry, but after refreshing my browsers cache I get an internal server error.

Comment: can you post your new .htaccess content? Perhaps it is something in the typing?